# Eclipse reorganizing packages and classes automatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I am having a strange situation where Eclipse is doing this.  Here is a screenshot:

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

Here is the screenshot of my Github repo where updates are pushed:

[image: Github screenshot]

Thus, I think 'src/noobchain' is the folder/package thing I want to keep and I want to delete the lower 'src' folder/package thing because it is a duplicate.  It wasn't like this before, I just had the 'src/noobchain' but then Eclipse did something on its own (I know this because I checked the Edit to undo and it was greyed out).
Now when I try to delete one or the other, they both get deleted.

So I came up with possible solutions in my head now which is to do a 'git pull' to my local after closing Eclipse and then restarting Eclipse.  But I'm wondering if someone else experienced this odd behavior by Eclipse Photon on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Looks like you haven't specified your source code folder, so it has assumed that it's src/noobchain which means all your classes are in the default package. Go to properties -> build path, and specify that src is a source folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as Goibniu suggested above by right clicking on src and then build path->use as source folder and I ended up with:

[image: updated project explorer screenshot]

It looks weird with two sets of the classes but I can run it so no complaints I guess.

When I try to delete the src it tells me it contains a Java source folder, it will delete the source folder as well.  Thus, I guess I have to leave it alone.  Not a perfect answer but it works.  If anyone has a better solution, please post.

Comment: If you use the Package Explorer view, only the source folder will show its contents.  There may be an empty "src" or "src/noobchain" showing as a plain folder, but there should not be any source files in it.  Project Explorer is trying to give you logical view (same as Package Explorer provides) and physical view (same as Navigator provides).  At times, this can be confusing.